# fetch public tweets via twitter api 1.1, via client side code (js)

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter, jsonp

I'm working on a basic personal homepage, consists of a single html document, a .css and jquery*.js file. I want to create a blog-ish look via fetching page content from tweets. The standart widget doesn't fit to the look of the page.

I can fetch public tweets from any account with no authentication crap (it's crap because it public data anyway) via API v1. But with API v1.1, it returns authentication error. It wants me to authenticate to fetch public data. Try to navigate  [this](https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?callback=?&screen_name=java) url. it shows `({"errors":[{"message":"Bad Authentication data","code":215}]});`.

My question is *is there a way to fetch public tweets via client side js*? I don't want to create an app to just fetch public data. I don't wan't to use identi.ca or else, but Twitter pushes me to do.

---

Upon the comment of Zachary Kinebel to Norguard's answer, I thought, as a comment  of Norguard's might be helpful to others, I should put it here:

---

`/search.json?q=from:nerdswguitars` === recent tweets by NerdsWGuitars `/search.json?q=to:nerdswguitars` === recent tweets to NerdsWGuitars `/search.json?q=from:nerdswguitars` OR `to:nerdswguitars` === both. `/search.json?q=@nerdswguitars` === posts involving NerdsWGuitars. `/search.json?q=#nerdswithguitars` === posts trending "nerdswithguitars". But you MUST make sure that you're properly URL encoding the query. Read more here: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/using-search and if you can't find what it is that you're looking for, out of this, then you need to be a lot more specific

Comment: Just tried G+ for same: wants oauth too.

Comment: This post helped a lot and I just completed the update for my twitter plugin, which uses JS to render and parse the requested Tweets (which must be retrieved via server-side scripting, per the new API - 1.1). The plugin can be found at http://zkniebel.github.com/jquery-twitter-feed/ and it includes sample server code to help get you going. The sample code uses `statuses/user_time` but the new `search/tweets` can be implemented with little change (update the URL and add/change the desired parameters).

Comment: @ZacharyKniebel and G: Twitter has now deprecated the Search API, and are forcing you to make an application, and do, at-minimum, application-level authentication, to make GET requests of their timeline. This is being sunsetted ~May.

Comment: @Norguard - read my comment above yours - I have addressed this issue

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### ***EDIT***

In the wonderful world of bad ideas, Twitter is sunsetting this answer, as of May 2013, and will require, at minimum, that you either use one of their widgets, and shoehorn it in, or that you set up an application and do application-level authentication, even for public-timeline `GET` requests.

If they change their mind, or delay the throwing of the switch, this will at least continue to be here.

---

Use the Search API:

```
"http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=nerdswguitars"
```

You can use the URL-encoded `#` or `@` in front of search terms.  You can also use keywords like `from` or `to`, and specify limits, et cetera.

Comment: What if someone mentioned me, or arbitarily use my name with having no relation to me? What if my user name is dave or jim or sth. else that a billion person has? There is no chance to limit the search to usernames (in the api, I know it is possible to filter manually). I won't search my **public** tweets.

Comment: Read the Search API documentation - it lays out all kinds of parameters.

Comment: @g_kaya `/search.json?q=from:nerdswguitars` === recent tweets by NerdsWGuitars `/search.json?q=to:nerdswguitars` === recent tweets to NerdsWGuitars `/search.json?q=from:nerdswguitars OR to:nerdswguitars` === both. `/search.json?q=@nerdswguitars` === posts involving NerdsWGuitars. `/search.json?q=#nerdswithguitars` === posts trending "nerdswithguitars".  But you ***MUST*** make sure that you're properly URL encoding the query. Read more here: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/using-search *and if you can't find what it is that you're looking for, out of this, then you need to be a lot more specific*

Comment: Thanks a lot. As far as I see, your answer is the best possible solution, I can use `/q=from:x` to get only x's tweets, but I'm really disappointed with the way Twitter altered their API.

Comment: I have to say, this is the best solution and is way too hard to find. I have been looking for this answer all day and it wasn't until I searched for "jQuery Twitter 1.1 widgets" that I finally found this. Anyone looking to update deprecated timeline plugins needs to see this! UP+++++++++

Comment: Unfortunately this is exactly what Twitter has turned off.

Comment: Yep, search.twitter.com is no more.

Comment: Down voted the answer because it is no longer relevant: "The Twitter REST API v1 is no longer active. Please migrate to API v1.1. https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/overview."

Comment: @wesmodes There’s not a whole lot I can do about that, Wes. I can’t delete an accepted answer (hence why I updated it in 2013, to mention that 1.0 was being sunset). Thanks for letting me know what I already (preemptively, I might add) admitted to, as the first sentence in my edited answer. Perhaps, instead of letting me know, you could instead let the question author know, so that he can deselect my answer. If you would prefer that I write “Edit 2” and go through OAuth tutorials, instead, let me know.

Answer (score 6):

You can use [Mooch](https://github.com/eloquent/mooch), a small application designed to solve this exact problem. Setting up a new *Mooch* service is very simple, and utilizes [Heroku](https://www.heroku.com/). The
deployment process requires the [Heroku Toolbelt](https://toolbelt.heroku.com/) application.

### Step 1: Create a Twitter app

- Visit https://dev.twitter.com/.
- Sign in with a Twitter account.
- [Create a new application](https://dev.twitter.com/apps/new).

### Step 2: Get *Mooch*

- Clone the Git repository (`git clone git@github.com:eloquent/mooch.git`).
- Change into the *Mooch* root directory.

### Step 3: Create a Heroku app

- Sign in with [Heroku Toolbelt](https://toolbelt.heroku.com/) (`heroku login`).
- Create a new app with `heroku create`.

### Step 4: Configuration

*Mooch* authenticates requests to the Twitter API using the [application-only
authentication](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/application-only-auth) method. This requires the consumer key and secret from the
Twitter application created in step 1.

#### Example authentication configuration

```
heroku config:set MOOCH_CONSUMER_KEY=xvz1evFS4wEEPTGEFPHBog
heroku config:set MOOCH_CONSUMER_SECRET=L8qq9PZyRg6ieKGEKhZolGC0vJWLw8iEJ88DRdyOg
```

### Step 5: Deploy

- `git push heroku master`

The new *Mooch* service should now be ready for use. Check the [Heroku
dashboard](https://dashboard.heroku.com/) for the service's location.

For more detailed configuration instructions, a demo application and more, check out the [Mooch README](https://github.com/eloquent/mooch#readme) on GitHub.