# Retrieve tweets and posts with only client-side code (no php)

Tags: javascript, html, facebook, twitter

I have a tricky question:
How would it be possible to retrieve tweets and facebook posts information with specific hashtag for example with only client-side code (html or javascript)?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you made a research?

Comment: Yes I did @zerkms. Apparently now we have to use OAuth authentification, I created an app to make secure request to twitter and facebook apis. I tried some basic resquests but nothing is working and all this seems a bit blurred to me..

Comment: well, it must work for facebook (since there is FB JS API) and I don't see how it would be possible to do with twitter.

Comment: seems is discontinued http://stackoverflow.com/a/13056877/1197775

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the public post search of Facebook to do this as descried here: [Need help on employing Graph Search parameters for hashtag query on facebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23340877/need-help-on-employing-graph-search-parameters-for-hashtag-query-on-facebook/23342041#23342041)

You can use the JavaScript SDK to do this on the client side. There was a similar question like yours today as well: [Need help on employing Graph Search parameters for hashtag query on facebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23340877/need-help-on-employing-graph-search-parameters-for-hashtag-query-on-facebook/23342041#23342041)

For Twitter, you could use the

```
GET search/tweets
```

endpoint as descibed here: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/search/tweets or use a Search Widget:

https://twitter.com/settings/widgets/new/search